# I'm using next.js and getting unnecessary top margin in index.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I'm using next.js and created this project using

```
yarn create next-app
```

And below is the bare minimum code. I don't know why

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p all tags are having default margin top in next.js

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/Index.module.css";

export default class index extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Index.module.css**

```
.container{
    background-color: aqua;
    min-height:100vh;
    width:100%;
}
```

**global.css**

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[image: unnecessary top margin]

Comment: Check if the <h1> tag has gotten a top margin to it.

Comment: @nadz yes now it's working but can you tell me why? because I have not mentioned the top margin for the h1 tag? is it default value in next.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to a margin collapse issue. You can read more about it [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/07/margins-in-css/).
To avoid it you can use the css `padding` property.

**EDIT**

You can use the padding property in place of the margin property like so:

```
h1 {
    padding-top: 20px
}
```

Comment: can you give a code example where to use padding property ?

Comment: @HemendraKhatik check the edited answer.

Comment: in my case margin-top: 0; is working but  padding-top: 20px is not working

Comment: Then try applying the padding to the parent. 
`.container { padding-top: 20px; }`